# Override standard "new" button in salesforce using LWC component

Tags: lightning, button, component, new

we have a custom visualforce page override on "new" button.we are implmenting lightning and in lightnng we are trying to use LWC component whch will redirect to standard new record page. the issue i am facing is i endup in a blank page with out errors. below is the code snippet.

NewLWC:

```
import { LightningElement, wire,track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class NewWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
@track hasRendered = true;
connectedCallback() {        
    if(this.hasRendered ){        
        console.log('easdasdasnter here'); 
        this.navigateToNewEventWithDefaults();
        this.hasRendered = false;
    }
 }

navigateToNewEventWithDefaults(){              
    var backgroundurl ='%2Flightning%2Fo%2FEvent%2Fhome';        
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: 'Event',
            actionName: 'new'
        },
        state: {
            count:'1',                               
            nooverride:'1',
            useRecordTypeCheck:'1',
            navigationLocation:'LIST_VIEW',
            backgroundContext:'/lightning/o/Event/home',                              
        }   
    });
}
```

}

NewAuraCmp:

```
  <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:actionOverride" access="global" >
<c:NewLWC></c:NewLWC>
  </aura:component>
```